# Need Help of using ChangePropertyAction usage in HierarchialDataTemplate present in usercontrol

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

Hi I have created a UserControl with RadTreeView and Iam using it in MainWindow.
In that usercontrol using a Hierarchial DataTemplate to load treeviewItems.

In that Hierarchial DataTemplate I am using Interaction triggers to select the underlying node when we click rightmouse button but it is not working.I think I am missing TargetObject property setting.It is working without usercontrol as Expected.

```
   <HierarchicalDataTemplate  ItemsSource="{Binding Nodes, Mode=OneWay}" x:Key="allLevelItemTemplate">
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding UserFriendlyName}" >           
               </TextBlock>
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseRightButtonDown">
                    <ei:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="IsSelected" Value="true" TargetObject="{Binding}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </Grid>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Please help me as I am  new to WPF UserControl.I strucked here.

Answer (score 0):

Since the target of the property you wish to change is the tree view item, you need to climb up the visual tree and find it:

```
TargetObject="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=rad:RadTreeViewItem}}"
```

(Replace `rad:` with the namespace you defined for the Telerik controls.)